# How do I merge MP3 files without re-encoding?

Tags: windows, mp3

I would like to merge multiple MP3 files on a Windows PC without decoding and re-encoding them. I don't mind if the final MP3 files loses the ID3 tags, but if it could somehow preserve the ID3 tags, that would be a bonus. I would also like to avoid issues with time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's technically not 'lossless' as MP3 is a lossy format. But you want to prevent any further loss of quality by decoding and re-encoding.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "without re-compression" in the body of the question

Comment: @benshepherd that's for Linux

Comment: I repeat my questions is specifically for Windows. The other question was specially for Linux.

Comment: the accepted answer of ffmpeg on the 'Linux question' can apply to Windows if you install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MP3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html) does what you want.

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) will probably do it too if you'd prefer a command-line method.

Comment: You made me be very interested in ffmpeg

Answer (score -3):

A Highly rate software Free-MP3-Joiner [link here](http://download.cnet.com/Free-MP3-Joiner/3000-18502_4-75860015.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to mention that it uses a lossless process to join MP3s

Comment: It is rated 5 stars in CNET. Since I have tried many softwares this one is the best out there retainging the original quality

Comment: @AugustusFrancis there is no proof for being really lossless. The fact you don't hear any difference is irrelevant here.